# error: package android.view does not exist on enabling view binding android

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Current Android Studio Version: 4.1.3

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

After enabling view binding in build.gradle I am getting the following error:

```
error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
```

in generated class FragmentFeedBinding

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't need to change anything in generated files at all.
try to clean and rebuild and see if that fixes your problem. Many times its android studio

Comment: OK how do I clean.  I can not find a "clean" anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I can work around this by forcing Android Studio to use java8 through JAVA_HOME.

Not great.